# Unexpected End of JSON Input when pulling JSON from Reddit

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am trying to pull some reddit posts from their json feed, as it is done in [this example](http://www.codingdefined.com/2015/12/get-latest-reddit-posts-in-nodejs.html):

```
var http = require('http');


function getRedditPosts() {
  var url = "http://www.reddit.com/r/jokes/new/.json?limit=1";

  var request = http.get(url, function(response) {
    var json = '';
    response.on('data', function(chunk) {
      json += chunk;
    });

    response.on('end', function() {
      var redditResponse = JSON.parse(json);
      redditResponse.data.children.forEach(function(child) {
    if(child.data.domain !== 'self.node') {
      console.log('-------------------------------');
      console.log('Author : ' + child.data.author);
      console.log('Domain : ' + child.data.domain);
      console.log('Title : ' + child.data.title);
      console.log('URL : ' + child.data.url);
    }
      });
    })
  });
  request.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
}

getRedditPosts();
```

The problem is that I am getting a unexpected end of JSON input. Why is that?

> undefined:1
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
>       at Object.parse (native)
>       at IncomingMessage. (/Users/felix/Desktop/Dev/npmTest/index.js:14:33)
>       at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
>       at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
>       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)

Comment: There is a typo in your url
`https://www.reddit.com/r/jokes/new.json?limit=1``

Comment: @FrançoisP. Thanks, weird. Postman accepted this just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, there is a typo in your url `reddit.com/r/jokes/new.json?limit=1`.

And you should use https instead of http package because reddit is https. 
Corrected code :

```
var http = require('https');


function getRedditPosts() {
  var url = "https://www.reddit.com/r/jokes/new.json?limit=1";

  var request = http.get(url, function(response) {
    var json = '';
    response.on('data', function(chunk) {
      json += chunk;
    });

    response.on('end', function() {
      var redditResponse = JSON.parse(json);
      redditResponse.data.children.forEach(function(child) {
    if(child.data.domain !== 'self.node') {
      console.log('-------------------------------');
      console.log('Author : ' + child.data.author);
      console.log('Domain : ' + child.data.domain);
      console.log('Title : ' + child.data.title);
      console.log('URL : ' + child.data.url);
    }
      });
    })
  });
  request.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
}

getRedditPosts();
```